# Monotonicity of rank of Ricci tensor under Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

Let $(M,g)$ be Riemannian manifold  , $Ric=\{R_{ij}\}$ is the Ricci tensor.
Whether the rank of Ricci tensor is monotonic ? In fact ,I want to show it is increase (non-decreasing).

Comment: What is the rank of the tensor?

Comment: @ArcticChar  rank of the matrix of $\{R_{ij}\}$